# Printing a diagonal line within a box in Java

Tags: java

For a class project, I must write a code that will print a box made of asterisks with a length specified by a user. There are two types of boxes we must make; basic and diagonal. The basic box is just a normal box made of asterisks, which I have already made. The diagonal box must have a diagonal line inside of it, looking something like this:
http://prntscr.com/3fbbot

Here is the code I have so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    Scanner type = new Scanner(System.in);
    Scanner number = new Scanner(System.in);
    Boolean f = true;
    while (f) {
        System.out.print("Enter a box type, basic or diagonal: ");
        String g = type.nextLine();
        if (g.equals("basic") || g.equals("diagonal")) {
        }
        else {
            continue;
        }
        System.out.print("Enter a number between 2 - 16: ");
        try {
            int boxSize = number.nextInt();
            if (g.equals("basic")) {
                if (boxSize >= 2 && boxSize <= 16) {
                    for (int i = 0; i < boxSize * boxSize;i++) {
                        int row = i / boxSize;
                        int col = i % boxSize;

                        if (row == 0 && col < boxSize-1) {
                            System.out.print("*");
                        }
                        else if (col == 0) {
                            System.out.print("*");
                        }
                        else if (col == (boxSize -1)) {
                            System.out.println("*");
                        }
                        else if (row == (boxSize - 1)) {
                            System.out.print("*");
                        }
                        else {
                            System.out.print(" ");
                        }
                    }
                }
                else {
                    System.out.println("Please use a proper integer.");
                }
                System.out.print("Make another square? Type yes or no: ");
                Scanner answer = new Scanner(System.in);
                if (answer.nextLine().equals("no")) {
                    System.out.print("Thanks for playing!");
                    System.exit(0);
                }
            }
            else {

            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("RESETTING. Please type an integer this time.");
        }
    }
}
```

If you need me to be more specific or need more details, just ask. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You will want to ask as specific a question as possible, to elaborate on your point of confusion. The more detail the better. Right now, all we see are some requirements and some code, and that's about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    while (true) {
        System.out.print("Enter a box type, basic or diagonal: ");
        String g = input.nextLine();
        if (!(g.equals("basic") || g.equals("diagonal"))) {
            continue;
        }

        System.out.print("Enter a number between 2 - 16: ");
        try {
            int boxSize = Integer.parseInt(input.nextLine());
            if (boxSize >= 2 && boxSize <= 16) {
            for (int i = 0; i <boxSize; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < boxSize; j++) {
                    if (i == j && g.equals("diagonal")) {
                        System.out.print("*");
                    } else if (i == 0 || i == boxSize-1) {
                        System.out.print("*");
                    } else if (j == 0 || j == boxSize-1) {
                        System.out.print("*");
                    } else {
                        System.out.print(" ");
                    }
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        } catch(Exception e){
                System.out.println("RESETTING. Please type an integer this time.");
        }

        System.out.print("Make another square? Type yes or no: ");
        if (input.nextLine().equals("no")) {
            System.out.print("Thanks for playing!");
            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You were creating multiple scanners which is unnecessary. Also, the diagonals are just when the row index == column index. This code should do what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Short and sweet answer could be:

```
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the size of the square: ");
    int n = input.nextInt();

        for(int i=1;i<=n;i++){  
                for(int j=1;j<=n;j++){  
                    if(i>1 && i<n && j>1 && j<n){ 
                        if(i==j){
                            System.out.print(" * ");
                        }else{
                        System.out.print("   ");
                        }  
                    } else{
                        System.out.print(" * ");
                    }
                }  
    System.out.println();
        }
```

Let me know if somebody else need more help on this.
Thank you.